# Pathfinder Office Differential Correction base provider list issue

Tags: pathfinder

In the differential correction wizard when I choose Select base provider, the distance to the provider is way off. (the distance shown is from my location) The .ssf files generated are from the Dominican republic.  I have updated the base provider list numerous times.

The base provider search list also shows the last base station used and that base station now is not in the list of available base providers?  It seems once I use a base provider one time I cannot select it again?

I have just found that my recent update to the base provider file, cbs_list.csv, is missing many countries that was originally present and the ones that I use. Does anyone know of a workaround or have a copy of a previous list?

Answer (score 0):

I will respond by saying this issue was in part "operator error"
The list update, cbs_list.csv, indeed had the base station code available so I assumed the name of the station was the same.  It was not.  When checking the column data I found the base station had a changed name and format.  In PFO when searching on the new name I was able to connect and correction.

Answer (score 0):

If the Base Station you want to use has been removed from the base provider file, there's usually a good reason for this, and finding an old copy of the base provider file will not magically restore the base.  One reason base stations are removed is because their storage format has changed - more and more bases are moving from RINEX 2.x format, which PFO supports, to RINEX 3, which PFO ***DOES NOT*** support.

If the base you want to use has changed to RINEX 3 format, you could look at downloading the RINEX 3.x files then converting RINEX 3 to RINEX 2.11, for example using the GFZRNX tool from this IGS site: http://acc.igs.org/software.html (I have not used this tool myself) then select the RINEX 2.11 files in PFO to use them for post-processing.